# Directory path selector input in web application - React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need to create a UI input for the user to select a directory path.
From what i've seen over the net everything is about uploading a directory or file,
what I need is a path selector.

My code is look somthing like this:

```
  <input
    type="file"
    id="flup"
    onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target)}
    webkitdirectory="true"
  />
```

but what I have now is an upload dialog instead of path selection.

For make my Intention more clear, what I'm looking for is somthing like a path selection for selecting a directory to install some software (but over a web application).

Comment: you can grab the path to that file, but you will always get a file upload dialog, there is no explicit path dialog

Comment: @EugenSunic upload dialog is the solution for this situation?

Comment: You want path to a LOCAL folder? Are you planning to use the [FileSystem api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API)?

Comment: @MoshFeu Thanks, but my point is to receive path from the user.
Just want the user to select the folder path, and i'll do the rest.